# How to disable Push down to refresh in Salesfoce1 App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, salesforce1-app

I'm developing a SF1 lightning Application using Aura and SLDS . I need to disable push down to refresh while navigating between various screens in the App.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable them in Standard screen then you can't disable them. Because it is SF1 native behaviour and you don't have any control on them.

In custom VF page we don't have such functionality. but in Standard page you can't do anything.